# N choose K, K-N, K-2N, etc, recursion within recursion

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, recursion

I know how to use recursion to generate all possible combinations, i.e. N choose K. But how to create all the possible N/K-groups of K? N is of course always divisible by K. To clarify: for example, if N is 20 and K is 4, then I want to generate all the possible five-groups-of-four. And if, say, N contains 1,2,3...20 and K is 4, then one such grouping is {1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16},{17,18,19,20}. Let's assume that N is relatively small, so recursion is feasible

I feel like this is a recursion-within-recursion problem, since generating all possible single-group-of-four (aka N choose K) requires recursion, and then generating the next group of four becomes N - 4 choose K, and the next N - 8 choose K, etc. But I'm having trouble implementing this...any help?

Comment: The number of combinations will be very large (you should estimate/compute it first to avoid surprise due to long execution time). You also should show your what you tried as it is unclear where  you "having trouble implementing this".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know it's large; hence N must be small. But I can't even think of a pseudocode beyond what I've written above...sorry I'm somewhat new to recursion. What should the "trivial base case" be for my problem?

Comment: 4-2, 6-2, 6-3 to start.  They are the 3 simplest cases.

Comment: Question on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640558/formula-for-n-k-groups-of-k-combinations) for the formula of the number of combinations.

Comment: You will have restrains on the input, meaning `k` will divide `n`?

Comment: @Alexandru Barbarosie He already said it: "N is of course always divisible by K. "

Answer (score 1):

Terminology: What you want is all [**partitions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Partition_of_a_set&oldid=582219511) of a set of N elements into parts of size K each. There are n!/((k!)^(n/k) (n/k)!) such partitions (see [answer on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640558/formula-for-n-k-groups-of-k-combinations/646460#646460)).

To avoid overgeneration, let's decide on a "canonical form" for each
  partition: let's say it is to write each part in increasing order, and then
  write these parts themselves in increasing order of their smallest element.

Now you can visualize generation of a partition as a process of dropping balls
  numbered 1 to N, one by one, into N/K bins. The constraint that each bin
  (part) must be in increasing order is then automatically satisfied (of course
  you should "read" each bin in the order in which elements were inserted), and
  the constraint on the parts is satisfied if we make sure we don't skip an empty bin
  before populating the next one.

Now to translate that into code. Let's model our partition (or bunch of bins) as a vector of vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

std::vector< std::vector<int> > partition;
int N, K;
int num_partitions_found = 0;

void OutputPartition();
```

In general, when generating structures recursively (or coding any recursive
  algorithm), your recursive function is given a particular "state", and tries
  each incremental way of extending that state. Between different options, just
  make sure to bring the state back to what you were given.

So let's write our recursive function to be one that takes a state in which balls up to `n-1` have been placed in bins, and extends the state by placing ball `n` in all possible places.

```
void GeneratePartitions(int n) {
  // When we've placed all N elements, output and stop.
  if (n == N + 1) {
    OutputPartition();
    return;
  }
  // Place ball n into each allowed bin.
  for (int i = 0; i < N / K; ++i) {
    // Cannot place into a full bin
    if (partition[i].size() == K) continue;
    // Cannot skip an empty bin
    if (i > 0 && partition[i-1].empty()) break;
    // Place the ball here: extending the state
    partition[i].push_back(n);
    // How to extend the new state is left to the recursive call
    GeneratePartitions(n + 1);
    // Make sure you restore state after each recursive call!
    partition[i].pop_back();
  }
}
```

That is the core of the recursion. The rest of the program is scaffolding.

```
void OutputPartition() {
  assert(partition.size() == N/K);
  ++num_partitions_found;
  for (int i = 0; i < N/K; ++i) {
    assert(partition[i].size() == K);
    std::cout << "{";
    for (int j = 0; j < K; ++j) {
      std::cout << partition[i][j] << (j == K - 1 ? "}" : ", ");
    }
    if (i < N/K - 1) std::cout << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::cin >> N >> K;
  assert(N % K == 0);
  partition.resize(N / K);
  GeneratePartitions(1);
  std::cout << num_partitions_found << " found" << std::endl;
}
```

Note: this post is a [literate program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming): if you put the code snippets together, you have a valid working program.

Alternatively, in case you'd like to try the program (see how fast it runs, etc.), a different version is [here on github](https://github.com/shreevatsa/misc-math/blob/master/so-21105154.cc): it doesn't use global variables, uses a plain array (faster) for the partition, and prints all found partitions only for small N (edit the code to change it).

To return to your question, we saw that by carefully thinking about the problem for a little while, you can avoid having different kinds of recursion. Even if you do, the general recipe for writing a recursive program stands: write a recursive function that takes a state, extends it by one step in all possible ways (passing off further extension of these states to a recursive call), and then cleans up to its original state. (Sometimes, when the state is small, you don't have to do any cleanup—you can pass along the state with the function call—but other times it's cleaner to have the state be shared by the recursive calls.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution uses recursion at two levels:

- find combinations C(n, k): k steps
- find a sequence of n/k C(n, k) : n/k steps

To avoid a repetition of the groups in a different order: first element in each group must be less or equal than the position.
A consequence is that the first group always starts with 1, by example.

Some results:

- 3 combinations for 4-2
- 10 combinations for 6-3
- 15 combinations for 6-2

I would like to know the calculation formula to further validate the results.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>

namespace lan
{

struct Solution
{
    virtual bool Next(const std::vector<unsigned>&) = 0;
};
void SetCombination(const size_t, const size_t, Solution*);

struct ToPrint: public Solution
{
    ToPrint(): m_cnt(0) {};

    void Print(const std::vector<unsigned>& solution, std::ostream& out, size_t grouped = 0)
    {
        assert(grouped <= solution.size());
        if (grouped)
            out<<"{";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < solution.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (i)
            {
                if (grouped && !(i%grouped))
                    out<<"} {";
                else
                    out<<" ";
            }
            out<<solution[i];
        }
        if (grouped)
            out<<"}";
        out<<std::endl;
    }

    bool Next(const std::vector<unsigned>& solution)
    {
        Print(solution, std::cout);
        ++m_cnt;
        return true;
    }

    size_t Count() const {return m_cnt;};

protected:
    size_t m_cnt;
};

struct GroupOf: public ToPrint
{
    typedef ToPrint Super;

    GroupOf(int length, int group, bool print): m_length(length), m_group(group), m_print(print)
    {
        assert(!(length%group));
        //m_out.open("out.txt");
        //assert(m_out);
    }

    bool Next(const std::vector<unsigned>& partial)
    {
        assert(m_group == partial.size());
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < m_group-1; ++i)
            assert(partial[i] < partial[i+1]);

        //  first element in each partial solution must be <= position (to avoid groups recombination)

        if (partial[0] > 0)
            return false;

        //  add the next group to the solution

        assert(m_sum <= m_length-m_group);
        size_t j, k; 
        for (i = j = k = 0; (i < m_length) && (j < m_group); ++i)
        {
            if (!m_solution[i] && (k++ == partial[j]))
            {
                j++;
                m_solution[i] = j + m_sum;
            }
        }
        assert(j == m_group);

        //  process a solution or go after the next group, recursively

        m_sum += m_group;
        if (m_sum == m_length)
        {
            std::vector<unsigned> print;
            Translate(m_solution, print); 
            if (m_print)
                //Print(print, m_out, m_group);
                Print(print, std::cout, m_group);
            assert(Validate(print));
            ++m_cnt;
        }
        else 
            SetCombination(m_length-m_sum, m_group, this);

        //  restore "stack" of recursive calls

        m_sum -= m_group;
        for (i = 0; i < m_length; ++i)
            if (m_solution[i] > m_sum)
                m_solution[i] = 0;

        return true;
    };

    void Start()
    {   
        m_sum = 0;
        m_solution.assign(m_length, 0);

        SetCombination(m_length, m_group, this);
    };

protected:
    //  transform positions to "real" solution
    static 
    void Translate(const std::vector<unsigned>& a, std::vector<unsigned>& b)
    {
        b.resize(a.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        {
            assert(a[i]);
            b[a[i]-1] = 1+i;
        }
    }

#ifdef _DEBUG
    static 
    bool Validate(const std::vector<unsigned>& a)
    {
        std::set<unsigned> elements; 
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
            elements.insert(a[i]);
        if (elements.size() != a.size())
            return false;

        return true;
    }
#else
    static 
    bool Validate(const std::vector<unsigned>&)
    {
        return true;
    }
#endif 

private:
    GroupOf& operator= (const GroupOf&);

protected:
    const size_t m_length;
    const size_t m_group;
    const bool m_print;

    size_t m_sum;
    std::vector<unsigned> m_solution;
    //std::ofstream m_out;
};

//  get a 'length' by 'group' combination; since it's strictly ordered ( = ... the order doesn't matter), the first index is "next"
bool SetCombination(const size_t length, const size_t group, size_t next, std::vector<unsigned>& solution, Solution* cbk)
{
    assert(length);
    assert(cbk);
    assert(group <= length);
    assert(next < length);

    for (size_t i = next; i < length; ++i)
    {
        solution.push_back(i);
        next = i+1;

        if (solution.size() == group)
        {
            if (!cbk->Next(solution))
                return false;
        }
        else if (next != length)
        {
            if (!SetCombination(length, group, next, solution, cbk))
                return false; //break;
        }

        solution.pop_back();
    }

    return true;
}

void SetCombination(const size_t length, const size_t group, Solution* cbk)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> solution;
    (void)SetCombination(length, group, 0, solution, cbk);
}

size_t Test(size_t total, size_t grouped, bool print = false)
{
    GroupOf test(total, grouped, print);
    test.Start();

    return test.Count();
}

}
```

All the results until now:

```
assert(3 == lan::Test(4, 2));
assert(10 == lan::Test(6, 3));
assert(15 == lan::Test(6, 2));
assert(126 == lan::Test(10, 5));
assert(280 == lan::Test(9, 3));
assert(945 == lan::Test(10, 2));
if (0)
{
    assert(1716 == lan::Test(14, 7));
    assert(5775 == lan::Test(12, 4));
    assert(126126 == lan::Test(15, 5)); //  1s, Release
}
```

Comment: I see the program uses 24.8% on my computer, so I have a quad-core processor. It would be interesting to parallelize the problem :).

Answer (score -1):

`std::next_permutation` may help:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int v[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    do
    {
        std::cout << "{" << v[0] << "," << v[1] << "," << v[2] << "}, "
                  << "{" << v[3] << "," << v[4] << "," << v[5] << "}" << std::endl;

    } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(v), std::end(v)));
    return 0;
}
```

which output (6! solutions)

```
{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}
{1,2,3}, {4,6,5}
...    
{6,5,4}, {3,1,2}
{6,5,4}, {3,2,1}
```

Or if order inside group doesn't matter, you may try the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int getNextIndex(const int (&v)[6], int start, int value)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(v) + start, std::end(v), value) - std::begin(v);
}

void print(const int (&v)[6])
{
    // Filter if you want that
    // `{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}` is equivalent to `{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}`
    if (getNextIndex(v, 0, 1) > getNextIndex(v, 0, 2)) return;
    //if (getNextIndex(v, 0, 2) > getNextIndex(v, 0, 3)) return; // And so on if you have more groups
    const char* sep[] = {", ", ", ", "}"};

    for (int i = 1; i != 3; ++i) {
        int index = -1;
        std::cout << "{";
        for (int j = 0; j != 3; ++j) {
            index = getNextIndex(v, index + 1, i);
            std::cout << 1 + index << sep[j];
        }
        std::cout << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int v[] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2};

    do
    {
        print(v);
    } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(v), std::end(v)));
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs (10 solutions):

```
{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6},
{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 6},
{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 6},
{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5},
{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6},
{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6},
{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5},
{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6},
{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5},
{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4},
```

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I think it solves OP problem (but without recursion).

Comment: I assume order within the groups shouldn't matter, order of groups shouldn't matter, etc. so... No.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Add a version where order doesn't matter.